# Copy Constructor and Operator Overloading : C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Consider Below example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{

public:
    int a;
    Test(int a=0):a(a){ cout << "Ctor " << a << endl;}
    Test(const Test& A):a(A.a){ cout << "Cpy Ctor " << a << endl;}
    Test operator+ ( Test A){
    Test temp;
    temp.a=this->a + A.a;
    return temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
Test b(10);
Test a = b ;
cout << a.a << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The Output is:

```
$ ./Test
Ctor 10
Cpy Ctor 10
10
```

It calls Copy constructor. Now, suppose If we modify the code as:

```
int main()
{
Test b(10);
Test a = b + Test(5);
cout << a.a << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The Output becomes:

```
$ ./Test
Ctor 10
Ctor 5
Ctor 0
15
```

The expression `Test a = b + Test(5);` does not call copy constructor. What I thought that that `b+ Test(5)` should be used to instantiate a new object `a` of type `Test` , so this should call copy constructor. Can someone explain the output?

Thanks

Comment: This has probably been answered before... see "copy elision" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision, i.e. the compiler is allowed to optimize copies.

Comment: Note that in `operator+` you do not need `temp`. You can use `A` directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 2):

See copy elision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

Basically, no temp is constructed and result is put directly into Test a object.